# Can C++-CLI dll be used in native application?

Tags: c++-cli

I am writing a dll in native code (C++) that is to be consumed by other native C++ applications.

One of the tasks of the dll is to perform XML file operations. C++ has poor support in dealing with XML files, e.g searching, writing, reading, as far as I know.

So, I am thinking if I can compile my dll code in clr:mixed mode and use the .NET XML assembly to do the XML related stuff. However, I still want my dll to be consumed by native C++ applications without any added hassles.

Will this approach work ? Any caveats to this ? Btw, is there any other XML library for C++ besides XMLlite ?

Comment: Doesn't boost have some xml parsing stuff?

Comment: TinyXML is an alternative to XMLite. http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html

Comment: I dont think they provide a good searching mechanism like LINQ to XML does in .NET